# javascript DOM hiding HTML div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to hide a div element from a javascript code in the game I'm making. I'm probably making a dumb mistake, but can someone please help me?

HTML:

```
 <div id="stats">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <text id="playerstats" style="width: 25%;height:30%;">You: <span id="playerhp">x</span>/<span id="playermaxhp">x</span> HP, <span id="playeratk">x</span> ATK, <span id="playerspd">x</span> SPD, <span id="playerdef">x</span> DEF.</text> <br>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <text id="enemystats" style="width: 25%;height:30%;">Enemy: <span id="enemyhp">x</span>/<span id="enemymaxhp">x</span> HP, <span id="enemyatk">x</span> ATK, <span id="enemyspd">x</span> SPD, <span id="enemydef">x</span> DEF. </text>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Javascript function to hide:

```
function hide(elemID) {

elemId = elemId.toString();
if (document.getElementById(elemId) != undefined) {
    document.getElementById(elemId).style.display = "none"; 
    return true;
}   else {
    console.log("Element '" + elemID + "' not defined.");
    return false;
}
```

When I go into the Chrome dev console, it always says that "elemID" is undefined no matter what I pass in (which is usually "stats"), and when I do breakpoints it shows me that is defined as "stats", then once it hits the if statement it returns the error.

Comment: elemID != elemId

Answer (score 2):

Your variable names were mismatched - `elemId` is not equal to `elemID` (note the capitalisation).

Try this instead:

```
function hide(elemID) {
    elemID = elemID.toString();
    if (document.getElementById(elemID) != undefined) {
        document.getElementById(elemID).style.display = "none"; 
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log("Element '" + elemID + "' not defined.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Alejandro - it's usually best to add a short description of the issue that you're resolving. I've edited the answer to reflect this. Thanks for the contribution!

Answer (score 1):

you are using to different variables in your function. In the function argument your variable is **elemID** but inside your function the variable you have used is **elemId**. You don't need to use `elemID = elemID.toString();` You can straightaway use **elemID** inside your function as follows;

```
function hide(elemID) {

    if (document.getElementById(elemID) != undefined) {
        document.getElementById(elemID).style.display = "none"; 
        return true;
    }   
    else {
        console.log("Element '" + elemID + "' not defined.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code. You can just create the reference to the DOM element once and use it both times it's referenced in your function. No need to find the DOM element twice.

You were referencing "elemID" as "elemId" inside your function. That's why "elemId" is undefined.

```js
function hide(elemID) {
    elemID = elemID.toString();
    let domElem = document.getElementById(elemID);
    if (domElem != undefined) {
        domElem.style.display = "none"; 
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log("Element '" + elemID + "' not defined.");
        return false;
    }
}

setTimeout(()=>{
  hide("stats");
}, 1000)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="stats">My Stats</div>
  </body>
</html>
```